Access crashes when opening report
I have a report that should only remain open if a filter is applied from a form. What I want to happen if the report is opened is that the filter is checked, and if found to be empty, a MsgBox appears, the report closes, and the form opens. What happens instead is that if I open the report directly from the database, it closes itself (check), the form needed opens (check), and the MsgBox appears twice (fail). Also, if the report is opened from the form (which should apply the filter to the report and worked before I added the autoclose code with MsgBox), Access crashes.
Report:
Private Sub Report_Close()
   Me.ReportCaption.Caption = ""
   Me.Filter = ""
End Sub


Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim filt As String
    filt = Me.Filter
    'MsgBox filt
    
    If Me.Filter = "" Then
       Me.ReportCaption.Visible = False
       DoCmd.Close acReport, Me.Name
       DoCmd.OpenForm "DataByAgencyF", acNormal
       MsgBox "Data is unfiltered. Please apply filter."
       Exit Sub
    Else: Me.ReportCaption.Visible = True
       Dim strAgency As String, strString As Long
       strAgency = filt     
       strStart = InStr(1, strAgency, "'")
       strAgency = Mid(strAgency, strStart + 1)
       strAgency = Left(strAgency, Len(strAgency) - 1)
       Me.ReportCaption.Caption = strAgency & " Case Outcomes"
    End If

    If CurrentProject.AllForms("AgencyOutcomesF").IsLoaded = True Then
        Me.Filter = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].Filter
        Me.FilterOn = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].FilterOn
        Me.OrderByOn = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].OrderByOn
        Me.OrderBy = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].OrderBy
    End If

End Sub


[DataByAgencyF] has a combobox with all the agencies and allows the user to select from that list to filter the data in two subforms.
SubForm [AgencyOutcomesF]:
Private Sub OpenReportBtn_Click()
    Dim filt As String
    filt = Parent!Agencies
    MsgBox filt
    DoCmd.OpenReport "AgencyOutcomesR", acViewPreview, , "[Agency]='" & filt & "'"
End Sub


Too complicated approach for a simple task. User should not have direct access to any object: table, report, form, module, ... Simply use menu or switchboard.

It's the same msgbox appearing twice or MsgBox filt & MsgBox "Data is unfiltered. Please apply filter."?

Two message boxes open because code is designed to show two. Are you positive opening from form with filter criteria crashes? I would expect opening without filter criteria would crash because that condition uses Close method in Open event. I doubt the Close event code is needed.

@Cyril MsgBox filt was used for testing purposes--that's not the duplicate MsgBox. I normally have the "filt" line commented out but forgot to do that here.
@June7 It's the "error" message that appears twice--not the MsgBox filt message. The form is constructed so that there is always at least a default option selected in the combobox, so there is always a filter option (i.e. Parent!Agencies). Clicking the "Open Report" button crashes Access.

Really should design GUI so users cannot activate objects directly from Navigation Pane. Aside from that, there could still be reasons to cancel opening a report. Use the Cancel parameter of report Open event and an error handler in procedure opening report to deal with the cancel action error message.
You declare strString but use strStart - I changed this to lngStart. Should include Option Explicit in all module headers so inconsistencies like this can be revealed. VBA Editor can be set to do this by default in new modules.
Private Sub OpenReportBtn_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim filt As String
    filt = Parent!Agencies
    MsgBox filt 'this msg may just be annoying to users and unnecessary
    DoCmd.OpenReport "AgencyOutcomesR", acViewPreview, , "[Agency]='" & filt & "'"
    If Err.Number = 2501 Then
        'cancel report error anticipated - do nothing
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strAgency As String, lngStart As Long
    If Me.Filter = "" Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Data is unfiltered. Please apply filter."
        DoCmd.OpenForm "DataByAgencyF", acNormal
    Else
        strAgency = Me.Filter      
        lngStart = InStr(1, strAgency, "'")
        strAgency = Mid(strAgency, lngStart + 1)
        strAgency = Left(strAgency, Len(strAgency) - 1)
        Me.ReportCaption.Caption = strAgency & " Case Outcomes"
        If CurrentProject.AllForms("AgencyOutcomesF").IsLoaded = True Then
            Me.Filter = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].Filter
            Me.FilterOn = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].FilterOn
            Me.OrderByOn = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].OrderByOn
            Me.OrderBy = Forms![AgencyOutcomesF].OrderBy
        End If
    End If
End Sub

To learn more about error handling in VBA, start with a review of http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html

I no longer get a crash, but I do get
`Run-time error '3709':
The search key was not found in any record.`
Debug leads to:
`Private Sub Report_Close()
Me.ReportCaption.Caption = ""
Me.Filter = ""
End Sub`
I want the filter to clear when the report closes.

As I said in earlier comment, that code is likely unnecessary - because the run-time changes are not saved in report design, at least not in my test.
